# Windows 10 Quick access and This PC not being populated

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-10-quick-access

I recently noticed a few times when clicking on either This PC or Quick access in Windows Explorer that the folders are not being populated with icons. The file system seems to be intact, as I can navigate to the drives that usually are displayed in This PC.

What happens is that the loading color overlay in the address bar located at the top of Windows Explorer seems to be endlessly searching. I also noticed that some of the icons I chose for some of the directories have gone back to the default icon

Also the Quick Access list on the left side of Explorer is no longer populated with any icons as well, with the 'Options' that is shown on right click being greyed out. I also can not access Folder Options in Explorer.

To remedy this I simply logged out, and back in again which seemed to temporarily solve the issue, however the problem does seem to persist so I would like to get a better understanding of what is happening to ensure system integrity.

Running Windows 10 Pro 64 bit
build Version   10.0.19045 Build 19045

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Also clean up (delete all) Quick Access items from the QA menu and restart

Comment: Quirky 3rd-party shell extensions are sometimes the cause of Intermittent **Explorer** issues as well. Have a look at: [Fixing shell extension problems with ShellExView](https://shellfix.nirsoft.net/shell_problems_list.html) .